# Infinity is assigned to min,max even though specific parameter is passed when initializing box3 class

Tags: three.js

This operation should be simple but getting unexpected behavior.
What I am trying to do is to initialize box3 class in Three.js by following code.

```
const roomBoxMin=new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
const roomBoxMax=new Vector3(1, 1, 0.1);
console.log('roomBoxMin',roomBoxMin);
console.log('roomBoxMax',roomBoxMax);
const roomBox = new Box3(
  roomBoxMin,roomBoxMax
);
console.log('roomBox',roomBox).
```

By this code, I expected to seem box3 instance with min(0,0,0) and max(1,1,0.1). However, what I got from console is following.
Could anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What version of Three.js are you using? You might be using an older version with bugs that were fixed later on because in this version `r126`, the results are as expected:

```js
const roomBoxMin = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
const roomBoxMax = new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 0.1);

const roomBox = new THREE.Box3(roomBoxMin,roomBoxMax);
console.log('roomBoxMax', roomBox.max.toArray());
console.log('roomBoxMin', roomBox.min.toArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.126.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
```